# Extracting specific information from IEnumerable using LINQ?

Tags: vb.net, linq, ienumerable

I have an IEnumerable which contains file and directory information - example below of its contents:-

[image]

I want to extract specific information from this IEnumerable and am assuming LINQ is the best route

I want a list of files and a separate list of directories in a given path - but just that level, so not including sub directories etc

So if I pass C:\ then it just returns list of files in root of C:\ and a list of directories in root of C:\ - 1 level only.  If I pass C:\Windows then it returns list of files in root of C:\Windows and a list of directories in C:\Windows - again just the level given and no lower (or higher)

The lists just need to contain the FullName of each file / directory and nothing else

The Attributes value contains Directory if a directory so I can use that to easily determine if a file or a directory using something similar to below

```
Dim dirs2 = nodes.Where(Function(n) n.FullName.StartsWith(path) And n.Attributes = Attributes.Directory)
Dim files2 = nodes.Where(Function(n) n.FullName.StartsWith(path) And n.Attributes <> Attributes.Directory)
```

But I am stuck on how I just return the FullName value - AND - how to just return one level

Example project linked below shows exactly how the IEnumerable is filled using NTFSreader [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ntfsreader/)

N.B. I want to continue using Ntfs reader and NOT use IO.Directory.GetDirectories / GetFiles as NTFS reader is much quicker and doesn't have same issue with permissions as it gets information directly from MFT

http://www.pcassistonline.co.uk/upload/test_source.zip

Anyone here got any thoughts please?  Have spent some hours with Google and other forums but at a loss here - thanks

Comment: If you just need the `FullName` property then select it. `Dim dirs2 = nodes.Where(Function(n) n.FullName.StartsWith(path) AndAlso n.Attributes = Attributes.Directory).Select(Function(n) n.FullName)`. For the top level part, go back to where you get the `nodes`, the method should have someway to dictate that. Check the overloads maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

In this example you can have both informations as `IEnumerable` of `Structure` `DFInfo` where inside have `Name` and `FullName`  *(for any convenience)*.

For only the `FullName` this code should be more slim cutting out `DFInfo` `Structure`.
Note that there is not necessary to use `Attributes` (as you shows) to see if is a `File` or a `Directory` as the methods `GetDirectories` or `GetFiles` returns only Directories or only Files.

Important to be mentioned you cannot get info by a SO protected `File` or `Directory` as a `Security Exception` comes out.

*Hope are what you need.*

```
Private Enum DF
    Directory = 0
    Files = 1
End Enum

Structure DFInfo
    Dim Name As String
    Dim FullName As String
End Structure

Private Function GetDFFromPath(path As String, whatINeed As DF) As IEnumerable(Of DFInfo)
    Dim elements As List(Of String)

    If whatINeed = DF.Directory Then
        elements = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*.*", searchOption:=SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList
    Else
        elements = IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", searchOption:=SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList
    End If

    If elements IsNot Nothing AndAlso elements.Count > 0 Then
        Return elements.ConvertAll(Function(str) New DFInfo With {.Name = New FileInfo(str).Name, .FullName = New FileInfo(str).FullName})
    End If

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim allDirs As IEnumerable(Of DFInfo) = GetDFFromPath("C:\", DF.Directory)
Dim allFiles As IEnumerable(Of DFInfo) = GetDFFromPath("C:\Windows", DF.Files)
```

And if you want to use NTFSReader work/improve those 2 instructions below:

```
    Dim rootDir = "C:\"
    Dim dirs2 As List(Of String) =
        nodes.Where(Function(n)
                        Return n.FullName = rootDir & n.Name And n.Attributes = Attributes.Directory
                    End Function).
    Select(Function(n) n.FullName).ToList

    rootDir = "C:\Windows\"
    Dim files2 As List(Of String) =
        nodes.Where(Function(n)
                        Return n.FullName = rootDir & n.Name And n.Attributes <> Attributes.Directory
                    End Function).
        Select(Function(n) n.FullName).ToList
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response

I don't want to use GetDirectories or GetFiles because a) it is too slow and b) the security issues you mention

That is why I am using NTFSreader - [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ntfsreader/) - because it very quickly gets information on all files/folders on an NTFS drive

So as per sample app I attached, this stores all results in an IEnumerable called in my case nodes.  So I want to pull all information I need from the nodes IEnumerable hence question about how I can get information out of this using LINQ

Comment: @DarrenRose Use this: `nodes.Where(Function(n) n.FullName.StartsWith(path) And n.Attributes = Attributes.Directory).Select(Function(s) New FileInfo(s).FullName)` So the part `.Select(Function(s) New FileInfo(s).FullName)` to get `FullName`. I doesn't know NTFSreader library

Comment: However to be sure you are getting those files or directories only in root path you have passed as parameter you can use for files: 

`… And (New IO.FileInfo(n.FullName).Directory = yourPathToExmine) And …`

And Directories :

 `… And (New IO.DirectoryInfo(n.FullName).Parent.FullName = yourPathToExmine) And ...`

Comment: Not sure why I need to use FileInfo and DirectoryInfo when the Nodes IEnumerable already contains all my information I need?   The first example gives an error by the way.  Not sure you need to know the NTFSreader library, though with example I posted it is easy to see output it gives, it is more of a LINQ expert I think I need

Comment: FileInfo and DirectoryInfo are to see if elements are not nested (subirectory).

Comment: okay I see, can you post the whole command in one go then and I will try it

Comment: Thank you, that is nearly perfect, apart it is missing some directories where Attributes contains more than just Directory e.g. C:\ProgramData has Attributes shown as "Hidden Or Directory Or NotContentIndexed" so think the bit where it says "n.Attributes = Attributes.Directory" needs to change somehow to cover those that include .Directory rather than just ones that ONLY have .Directory - does that make sense?

Comment: Edit: actually tried it on some other locations and it isn't working

Comment: @DarrenRose As I wrote in my answer (work/improve those 2 instructions) as there is to poor to get directories to your interest (only with =/<> Attributes.Directory). About other clients I think your app needs permissions as Administrator to be executed. Was for that I propose you the other solution above. The solution above returns you all but you cannot interrogate (to get info) a protected File Or Directory.
Have nice weekend :)

Comment: using ntfsreader I can get information on all files / directories - as it avoids the permission issue, hence why I chose to use it, it is also very quick, getting information on ALL on my C: drive in just over 3 seconds.  "628.307 MB of volume metadata has been read in 3.086 s at 203.579 MB/s
599600 nodes have been retrieved in 683.7102 ms"

Comment: This is not true. Even Visual Studio which run Projects under a her SandBox ask you to re-start VS as Administrator if you are using NTFSReader library. 
Get more info about. :)

Comment: i didn't mention running as admin - yes both methods run as admin, BUT ntfsreader can access files and directories that System.IO can't as it gets information directly from MFT - that is why I use it, it is also much quicker as I said

Comment: I was referring to permissions to access some files/folders e.g. those that give system.io.ioexception errors etc not permissions to run the app..

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dirs As List(Of String) = nodes.Where(Function(n)
                             Return n.FullName = path & n.Name AndAlso ((n.Attributes And Attributes.Directory) = Attributes.Directory)
                             End Function).Select(Function(n) n.FullName).OrderBy(Function(n) n).ToList


Dim files As List(Of String) = nodes.Where(Function(n)
                               Return n.FullName = path & n.Name AndAlso ((n.Attributes And Attributes.Directory) <> Attributes.Directory)
                               End Function).Select(Function(n) n.FullName).OrderBy(Function(n) n).ToList
```

and need to ensure "path" has a trailing \ e.g. C:\ or C:\Windows\ and NOT C:\Windows as if not won't work

All input appreciated :)